# Best way to handle huge real time data from GPS device

Tags: architecture, gps, real-time, message-queue

We are trying to build a tracking application which will track all the GPS device location and other parameters in real time.

The GPS devices will send data continuously to the server and we need to decode the data to store and display the same in a web portal/mobile application.

Our initial thoughts was to use API to get data from the GPS devices but since there will be thousands of request per minute, there is high chance the web server may not be able to serve and we may lose the GPS data. So we are thinking about using the Message Queue to handle the real time data.

Our though process is "GPS devices will send the real time data to a message queue. There could be a service running on the server that will be listening to the queues and will update the database if any data is received. From the mobile application perspective, when the app is opened, it will be listening to the queue and fetch the data to display the same in application."

Kindly help us to choose the right architecture to handle the real time data from a GPS device.

If message queue is the right way to go forward, will [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) be the right choice?

Here we are speaking about minimum of 1,000 GPS devices always connected and transmitting the data.

Comment: Would Apache Kafka be a good fit for your use case?  https://kafka.apache.org/

Comment: Have you considered event stream services from cloud providers ? if not i would recommend. Choose one of the managed services. e.g. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/event-hubs/